# ng-options not updating select tag

Tags: angularjs

In the following code taken from my app, the dropdown is not getting updated with the scope data. How can I make this work? I need to pass the dropdown options from parent controller to child controller. I am getting [$injector:modulerr] error.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="parentCtrl as pt">
  <button ng-click="pt.callChild()">Change Dropdown</button>
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl as ct">
      <select ng-model="ct.selectedName" ng-options="item for item in ct.names">
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('parentCtrl', function ($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  var newArray = ["Steve", "Jony"];
  vm.callChild = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', newArray);
  };
});

app.controller('childCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];

    $scope.$on('someEvent', function (e, newArray) {
      vm.names = newArray;
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk49/zu089s6d/1/).

Comment: if the initial binding is not working it's not surprising that the whole thing does not work. Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: You can see the message by opening the console in fiddle. But posting it here as well: VM66 angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)(…)

Comment: Sorry did not notice the fiddle when i wrote the comment

Comment: Anyways, as Navoneel says, it's a JSfiddle issue, anywhere else it should

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine for me and I have incorporated angular 1.5 version.

See <kbd>[plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/62jkimfxCRbBUsVunm3X)</kbd> .

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="parentCtrl as pt">
  <button ng-click="pt.callChild()">Change Dropdown</button>
  <div ng-controller="childCtrl as ct">
    <select ng-model="ct.selectedName" ng-options="item for item in ct.names">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```